# Multiple connections are used even when shareNativeConnection is enabled in spring-data-redis LettuceConnectionFactory

Tags: connection, spring-data-redis, lettuce

We are using spring-data-redis with lettuce under the hood. 'shareNativeConnection' is enabled by default. We currently only have get and set calls to Redis.

From the connection event logs, I see connection events with different ports (offcourse same IP). My understanding is that lettuce uses single connection for multiple requests for non-blocking calls. Does multiple ports here mean it is creating new connection for each request? What does different port represent?

```
Event:ConnectedEvent [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:47378
Event:ConnectedEvent [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:47380 
Event:ConnectedEvent [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:47434
```

versions:
Lettuce:6.3.1.RELEASE
sping-data-redis:3.2.3
Redis: 6.4.2